# In IE top:50% works relative to text, not entire element

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have an `a` element with a `display: table-cell;` and `position: absolute;`.

I am trying to position a character inserted with `:after` to display exactly halfway down the `a` element, for this I use `top: 50%;` and `transform: translateY(-50%);`. This works perfectly in Chrome (of course), but in IE this pseudo element still displays very near the top. After some investigation i realised that this does display at the proper height when there is more text inside the `a`. My interpretation of this is that IE calculates the top value from the height of the text, not the entire element. Why it does this is beyond me.

In any case, how can I position this properly in IE?

This is the html:

```
<div class="cta-footer">
    <div class="cta-footer__section cta-footer__share-section">
        <!-- stuff -->
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="cta-footer__section cta-footer__cta">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet 
    </a>
</div>
```

This is my Sass:

```
.cta-footer {
    display: table-row;
    &__section {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border: none;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 20px;
        width: 50%;
    }
    &__cta {
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 20px;
        padding-right: 35px;
        &:after {
            display: inline;
            position: absolute;
            content: "\e021";
            top: 50%;
            transform: translateY(-50%);
            right: 12.5px;
            left: auto;
        }
    }
}
```

This is how the div appears in Chrome:
[image]

This is how it appears in IE:
[image]

As you can see the arrow is much higher in IE, because the top value is calculated from the height of the node text, not the actual element.

How can I make this consistent cross browser?

Comment: can you please make fiddle or codepen ?

Comment: i wish I could but this is part of a massive project with a ton of styles in various stylesheets and reproducing everything would just be too much. Sorry.

Comment: i want just specific area or can you share a link ?

Comment: the link is not working for me

Comment: Try this: http://unilever-lab.amaze.com/slp-2016/sustainable-living-2016/case-study.html

Comment: its seems that transform: translateY(-50%); is missing from your live site

Comment: I've just updated the live site.